# JAX-RS support in JBoss (Apache CXF, JBoss Resteasy)

Tags: rest, jboss, jax-rs, cxf, resteasy

I'm working on a java RESTful client using Apache CXF's Proxy-based API, deploying to **JBoss 5.1**.
Here's my dependency in POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've written a test and it works just fine, but it doesn't work in application after deployment to JBoss. It fails with NPE after application start because @SessionContext was not injected for some reason and is null.

I suppose that there are some conflicts between dependencies, because when I change above POM to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

the application works fine (!) until it creates a proxy:

```
authenticationProxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create(
    myServiceUrl, 
    IAuthenticationResource.class,
    Collections.singletonList(jsonProvider));
```

At this point it hangs and fails by timeout.
I've tried to use Resteasy instead of CXF and had the same problem.
I've tried to detect conflicts in my POM using maven plugins, but it gave nothing.
I think that the problem is in JBoss. Does JBoss 5.1 support JAX-RS 2.0? Is there a default implementation of it within JBoss? Can I use Apache CXF 3.x.x in JBoss 5.1? Please advise

Comment: JBoss 5 supports Java EE 5. JAX-RS 2 is part of Java EE 7 which will be supported by JBoss EAP 7 (hopefully some day next year). Currently you can use the community version wildlfy or try to upgrade yourself. Here's [an example for JBoss AS7 / EAP 6](https://dzone.com/articles/jboss-modules-suck-it%E2%80%99s).

Comment: So I can't use any JAX-RS implementation for consuming REST services in JBoss 5.1?

Comment: I don't know, never tried. It's not supported out of the box. There may be a may which may work.

Answer (score 2):

JAX-RS 2.0 is part of [Java EE 7 Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile) and JAX-RS 1.1 is part of [Java EE 6 Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile).

JBoss AS 7.1 uses RESTEasy with JAX-RS 1.1, see [JBoss AS 7.1 - JAX-RS Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JAX-RS+Reference+Guide).

JBoss AS 6 uses RESTEasy , see [RESTEasy JAX-RS](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#JBoss%20AS%206).

JBoss AS 5 has no implementation of JAX-RS, see [RESTEasy JAX-RS](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#JBoss5), but some issues:

> Resteasy has no special integration with JBoss Application Server so it must be configured and installed like any other container. There are some issues though. You must make sure that there is not a copy of servlet-api-xxx.jar in your WEB-INF/lib directory as this may cause problems. Also, if you are running with JDK 6, make sure to filter out the JAXB jars as they come with JDK 6.

If you use JBoss EAP 5.1 you find versions of JBoss AS, RESTEasy and Apache CXF at [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 5](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_5).

Comment: I had the same issue with Jboss 5.1 and JDK 6. My project was deployed as an EJB module in a EAR, i added the following dependency exclusion to the ejb dependency: 
             <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
              <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
              <groupId>sun-jaxb</groupId>
             </exclusion>
            </exclusions>